# Drupal 7 function to format an image URL?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am creating a module in Drupal 7. If I want to format a UNIX timestamp into a date I can use the format_date function, like so:

```
$date = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'j F Y');
```

Is there also a function I can reference to format an image? Say my database query returns

```
picture-4-136576449.png
```

from a table and I want to transform it into:

```
<img src="/images/picture-4-136576449.png />
```

is there a function to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to convert a `URI` to a URL, you are doing it wrong.

```
$uri = 'public://images/my-photo.png';
$url = file_create_url($uri);
// $url should be publicly accessible URL now.
```

If you know the path to the image relative to Drupal root, use

```
$url = url('path/to/image.png', array('alias' => FALSE));
```

You can theme an image using [`theme('image', $variables)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7).

ex:

```
<?php 
print theme('image', array('path' => 'path/to/image.png', 
                           'title' => t('Some title'), //optional
                           'alt' => t('Some alt text'), //optional
                      ));
```

You can see the other variables at theme_image() function [doc page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7).

Comment: Thanks, theme_image was what I was looking for. When you say 'theme an image'. What does that mean?

Comment: To return HTML img tag from given variables. However, use theme() function (example above) instead of theme_image.